# Integrate LazyPagingItems withing a HorizontalPager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

Following case: I have a `LazyColumn` displaying items coming from `LazyPagingItems`. These items come from a `RemoteMediator` (an API-Call is made and afterwards the items are inserted into a Room database). To implement the paging correctly, the also exists an entity holding the position data (page, nextPage, previousPage, positionInPage, nextItem and previousItem).

Now the problem: When I click an Item (let's assume we click item X: `X(page=8, positionInPage=13)` I want to navigate to another composable, which displays the the detail view of that Item. In this composable implemented a `HorizontalPager` which should also get the data from the `LazyPagingItems`. My problem is, that the `PREPEND` loadType is not called (for example, when I slided to item Y: `Y(page=8, positionInPage=0)`). Is it possible to integrate a `HorizontalPager` correctly with `LazyPagingItems`?

Thanks for your answers!